# Epson Perfection V600 Photo Scanner 64-bit

Tags: scanner

It works with Ubuntu 12.04 (32-bit) but in 16.04 (64-bit) the V600 do not work for me.

```
$ scanimage -L
device `epkowa:usb:001:013′ is a Epson (unknown model) flatbed scanner
```

Iscan or XSane do not work for me.

Installed:

- Sane
- Epson data package
- Epson core package
- Epson plug-in package

In epkowa.conf added line: usb 0x04b8 0x013a (this was not needed in epkowa for 12.04 32-bit)

Is there a problem with the Epson 64-bit driver or what do I do wrong?

I use Epson Scanner Driver Version 1.0.1 Release date 07-04-2016
[Scanner Driver](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule)

All other connected USB units works, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth and kvm-switch.

Scanner connected to USB2 at Motherboard.

Motherboard Asus H170M-PLUS

XHCI disabled.

### From Bios Manual:

XHCI Hand-off [Disabled]

[Enabled]       Enables the support for operating systems without an XHCI hand‐off feature.
[Disabled]       Disables the XHCI Hand-off support.

Comment: The driver is [HERE](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX) It works for me.

Comment: I did use that driver, did you make it to work with the V600?

Comment: Yes, it works with V600.

Comment: In some cases you will need to disable xhci in BIOS settings.

Comment: xhci is disabled as default, please see more detail above.